# OpenApi 3.0 one or more field requiered

Tags: swagger, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin, openapi-generator-cli

Body

```
{
  "param1": "string", #required or
  "param2": "string", #required or
  "param3": "string", #required 
  "param4": true,
  "param5": "string"
}
```

one or more params are required.

which is yaml sintax for define parm1 or parm2 or parm3 required?

thx.

Answer (score 0):

Does restricting the number of object property count with `"minProperties": 3` work for you? If it doesn't fit you, then you will need very complicated if-then-else structures to express this (in which case it is just better to implement this check with programmatic validation, rather than in the json schema).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use OpenAPI 3.x, you need a combination of `anyOf` + `required`:

```yaml
type: object
anyOf:
  - required: [param1]
  - required: [param2]
  - required: [param3]
properties:
  ...
```

This syntax means: at least `param1` or `param2` or `param3` (or any combination of these properties) must be present.

Comment: this solution generate an error on maven install: symbol:   class AnyOfobjectobjectobject

Comment: Sounds like a codegen bug. Open an issue at https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues or check if there's an existing issue.